# Convert mongodump BSON files to Parquet

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I am trying to convert the data from a mongoDB dump to a parquet format. I am using python, pymongo and a shell script for that.

When I run the shell script to dumb the data I got a lot of BSON files, I did not find a way to direct convert BSON -> Parquet, so I am trying to do BSON -> JSON -> Parquet.

However I have no clue of how convert those BSON files to JSON, I tried the bson.decode_file_iter() from Pymongo, it returns a generator I don't know what to do with that.

```
<generator object decode_file_iter at 0x000002582B3F4C50>
```

I also tried the bson.json_utils but I also did not figured out how to use it. When I used the dump method I got some strange string like.

```
 ["\u00e3\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007_id\u0000[\u0007\u0012\u00f51\u02dc}n#\u00ff\u00d5)\u0002\"login\"\u0000\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000araan\u0000\u0002\"nome\"\u0000\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000araan\u0000\u0002\"perfil\"\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000gerente\u0000\u0002\"solucao\"\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000raizen\u0000\u0002\"senha\"\u0000A\u0000\u0000\u00008d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92\u0000\u0002_class\u0000\"\u0000\u0000\u0000com.tm.attendex.api.model.Usuario\u0000\u0000"]
```

EDIT: I tried to iterate over the generator and got the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/fabio/PycharmProjects/MongoDump/mongodump.py", line 18, in <module>
    for row in gen:
  File "C:\Users\fabio\PycharmProjects\MongoDump\venv\lib\site-packages\bson\__init__.py", line 971, in decode_file_iter
obj_size = _UNPACK_INT(size_data)[0] - 4
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bson.decode_file_iter() ([documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.8/api/bson/index.html)) returns a generator because the bson dump file can be huge. You may iterate over the generator to get each row as a dict (the default value for 'as_class' argument of the function) where column names are the keys and the values are the corresponding values of that row.

To convert the bson to json, you may put each row dict in a list and then dump the list into a json file,

```
import bson
import json
gen = bson.decode_file_iter(open('table1.bson')) 
json_list = [] 
for row in gen:
     json_list.append(row)
json.dump(json_list, open('table1.json','w')
```

But it would be really up to the RAM size. If the dump is big, the `json_list` will take up all the memory space. I would prefer to write it in a file line by line.

Specially, when you are interested in Parquet (rather Hadoop ecosystem), I am assuming you're dealing with big data. You may try doing the bson->json->Parquet in batches, keeping a count of rows you add in the list to dump as json.

Comment: Thank you for the response I tried the code however got the error that i pasted at the EDIT section. Maybe is something due to how python open files and the default encoding? (I am using windows right now, however once finished the script will probably run at an linux EC2 instance)

Comment: As per your edit, your "gen" seem to be a string. The above code sample runs fine with python 2.7 on ubuntu. But I don't think windows environment can be a problem.